# Application stop/start during EC2 autoparking

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, redhat

I need to autopark EC2 instance on weekends, this requires stopping application during shutdown and starting the same on EC2 startup on Monday. How do I and where should I put the stop/start application scripts in Linux (RHEL).

Answer (score 1):

"Autoparking" isn't a term used in AWS, but the general idea of stopping an instance or instances on the weekend is probably a common requirement.

There are a few ways to do this:

- Log into the console and hit the "stop" button.
- [AWS Instance Scheduler scripts](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/stop-start-instance-scheduler/) to do what you're trying to achieve.
- Even easier, you might be able to use [scheduled scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/schedule_time.html) if it accepted a maximum of 0 instances for some periods
- You could write an AWS Lambda script that does exactly what you want

You don't really need to run stop scripts on your instances. If you do, you still need to tell AWS to stop the EC2 instance to make sure you're not charged. I've never tried stopping the OS to see if the VM is automatically stopped at the hypervisor level.

You could potentially use the AWS CLI running on the instance, with an appropriate IAM role, to tell AWS to shut itself down. Then it would be a script run by a cron job. Of course that is half the problem, it can't start itself. A single small server running could start all the other servers though. A lambda function on a Cloudwatch events timer would be cheaper.

Comment: Can you tell me the possible ways to do it from server end, like rc scripts , I don't have much knowledge of this .

Comment: Sorry but you're going to have to do some work to learn AWS to do this. If you shut down your server you can't run a script on the stopped server to start it again.

Comment: Thanks Tim , really appreciate the inputs , I will try to implement those.